# How can I replace anything before first forward slash using bash script?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, github

Using GitHub workflow I have the following command

```
echo MY_DIR=$(echo "${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

This would return a value like `something/something-else/another`

I am looking to add to this script to replace everything before the **first forward slash** with **thisword**

Which would output `thisword/something-else/another`

Can regex be used on the single line script to do this replace? I believe I could use the following regex `/^[^/]+/` but unsure how to combine with the current script.

Comment: Where do you have this "command"? I don't know any command starting with `MY_DIR=`.

Comment: I missed the echo part, which is added now. The output of the script in MY_DIR is then used later in the workflow

Comment: Are you sure the echo belongs into the double quotes? It doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version and distro of sed (apologies, but there are many with different syntax and flags), you might be able to do something like:

```
echo MY_DIR=$(echo "${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/^[a-z]*\//thisword\//' )
```

Sed is finding-and-replacing a string of text starting from the beginning of the line `^` which contains any number of occurrences `*` of lowercase characters in any order `[a-z]` which are then followed by the first slash.  The slashes can be escaped by using the backslash character `\`.  To clarify sed's use of `/`, here's the same expression omitting the regex and slashes forming part of your search string: `sed 's/find/replace/'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MY_DIR` holds `something/something-else/another`, you can use

```sh
MY_DIR="something/something-else/another"
MY_DIR="thisword/${MY_DIR#*/}"
echo "$MY_DIR"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kPhUMp).

This is an example of string variable expansion where `#` means "replace as few chars as possible from the left", and `*/` glob matches any text up to a `/` including it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex

```
^([a-z]*)(\/)



function formatData() {
  var str = "something/something-else/another";
  var res = str.replace(/^([a-z]*)!?(\/)/gim, "otherword/");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```